# When I update an attribute programatically, it doesn't reflect on admin. Why?

Tags: php, magento

I have an attribute post_to_amazon that can be set to Yes or No on the product.
This is my code:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load("83061");
echo $_product->getPostToAmazon();
$_product->setData("post_to_amazon", "11063");
$_product->save();
```

The echo prints 11063 which is the value for Yes but i'm not seeing Yes selected for the dropdown on admin.
[image]
[image]

Why isn't the dropdown showing Yes when the echo is showing 11063?

Here are the settings for my attibute. I'm using Magento 1.9.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I was missing this after Mage::app()
  
`Mage :: app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App :: ADMIN_STORE_ID);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code hope this might useful to you.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load("83061");
echo $_product->getPostToAmazon();
$attrCode = 'post_to_amazon';
$valueText = ('Yes');
$valueId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource()->getOptionId($valueText);
$_product->setData($attrCode, $valueId);
$_product->save();
```